# PHP - How to Compare given int/float value is within a (min & max) range and yet show all in default

Tags: php, comparison, max, operator-keyword, min

The application has one text box for input Minimum `$min` number and another text box for input Maximum `$max` number.

Result of `$total` is auto generated from database.

I know the logic as following to find the given value within the range:

```
if($total >= $min && $total <= $max)
```

I also would like to showing value that is not zero.

```
if($total > 0)
```

Example:

1) In database

```
| $id | $total |
----------------
|  1  |   15   |
|  2  |   38   |
|  3  |   22   |
|  4  |   0    |
|  5  |   56   |
|  6  |   43   |
```

2) Without filter of min and max. But must more than zero (by default).

```
| $id | $total |
----------------
|  1  |   15   |
|  2  |   38   |
|  3  |   22   |
|  5  |   56   |
|  6  |   43   |
```

3) With `$min` = 20 and `$max` = 50

```
| $id | $total |
----------------
|  2  |   38   |
|  3  |   22   |
|  6  |   43   |
```

4)  With `$min` = 20 and `$max` = empty

```
| $id | $total |
----------------
|  2  |   38   |
|  3  |   22   |
|  5  |   56   |
|  6  |   43   |
```

4)  With `$min` = empty and `$max` = 40

```
| $id | $total |
----------------
|  1  |   15   |
|  2  |   38   |
|  3  |   22   |
```

How to achieve above results?

Comment: Just need to do more checks on the input vars and change the query. You don't want to put it in one megalithic single if statement.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone The result shows empty according to your solution.